# Disabled pseudo-class not working after minification

Tags: css, minify, pseudo-class, gulp-clean-css

currently I'm using the following plugin:

[gulp-clean-css](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css)

This is my layout:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
    <span class="checkbox-material" style="margin-right: 10px">
       <span class="check"></span>
    </span>I'm supposed to be checked and disabled
  </label>
</div>
```

Then in my CSS:

```
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked+.checkbox-material .check {
    color: #2196f3; // when the input's disabled is set to false
}


.checkbox input[type=checkbox][disabled]:checked+.checkbox-material .check{
        color:#9E9E9E!important;cursor:not-allowed!important; // When the input is disabled
}
```

The issue is that when I run the code optimized, (minified) The second selector is not being taken in account. Although it exists on the stylesheet

Any ideas?

Comment: A demo would be useful but this seems to work when there is something in the actual `.check` span - https://jsfiddle.net/7o4qL3th/

Comment: @Paulie_D It might be that he is missing a `;` after the `cursor` property value.

Comment: @Paulie_D Here is a Fiddle with the whole css minified.http://codepen.io/dgoncalves1/pen/QKaQYj